# The OpenTextFile is overriding opened text file by clearing it

Tags: vbscript

I am currently having a problem with OpenTextFile. I created a script over a year ago. Recently, the script started giving me problems. It's clearing the first text file and giving me an error.

```
    Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
    myFile = objArgs(0)
    numberofTXT = objArgs(1)
    line = objArgs(2)
    
    Set f = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(myFile, line)
    d = f.ReadLine
    
    Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    outFile=numberofTXT
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
    objFile.Write d & vbCrLf
    objFile.Close
```

This is a super basic script I wrote to explain my issue. Takes in 3 files as arguments. For example LOL.txt, Hi.txt, and a specific line of LOL.txt (Why did 13-year-old me give examples using the word Lol, oh my gosh). This is meant to read the first file and write the data from the first file to the second file.

This issue was due to my current understanding (when I posted this) and not knowing what documentation was. I was self-taught. Please make sure to read the documentation if you have any issues with [OpenTextFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method) and make sure your arguments are correct for the function.

Comment: So, you want read all lines from LOL.txt file and write them to Hi.txt with Cscript in command line ?

Comment: I would like to read one line from Lol.txt and write to it to Hi.txt like example I would like to write 2 line from Lol.txt to Hi.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read and apply the [`OpenTextFile` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s(v=vs.84).aspx) reference:

> Opens a specified file and returns a TextStream object that can be
>   used to read from, write to, or append to the file.
>
> *Syntax*
>
> ```
> object.OpenTextFile(filename[, iomode[, create[, format]]])
> ```
>
> *Arguments*
>
> - `object`   *Required*. Object is always the name of a `FileSystemObject`.
> - `filename` *Required*. String expression that identifies the file to open.
> - `iomode`   *Optional*. Can be one of three constants: `ForReading`, `ForWriting`, or `ForAppending`.
> - `create`   *Optional*. Boolean value that indicates whether a new file can be created if the specified filename doesn't exist. The value
>     is `True` if a new file is created, `False` if it isn't created. If
>     omitted, a new file isn't created.
> - `format`   *Optional*. One of three Tristate values used to indicate the format of the opened file (`TristateTrue = -1` to open the file as
>     Unicode, `TristateFalse = 0` to open the file as ASCII,
>     `TristateUseDefault = -2` to open the file as the system default). If
>     omitted, the file is opened as ASCII.
>
> *Settings*
>
> The `iomode` argument can have any of the following settings:
>
> ```
> Constant     Value Description
> ForReading   1     Open a file for reading only. You can't write to this file.
> ForWriting   2     Open a file for writing.
> ForAppending 8     Open a file and write to the end of the file.
> ```

Read [`CreateTextFile` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c(v=vs.84).aspx) reference as well. Then, the following *commented* code snippet could help:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objArgs      = WScript.Arguments
myFile           = objArgs(0)         ' file to read
numberofTXT      = objArgs(1)         ' file to write
line             = objArgs(2)         ' line serial number to write into output file
                                      ' (or number of lines?)
Set objFSO       = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

outFile=numberofTXT
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)

Set f = objFSO.OpenTextFile(myFile, ForReading) 

lineindex = 1
Do until f.AtEndOfStream
    d = f.ReadLine
    if lineindex = line Then     ' only take the line-th line 
        objFile.Write d & vbCrLf ' or objFile.WriteLine d
        Exit Do   ' transfers control to the statement immediately following Loop statement
    End If
    lineindex = lineindex + 1
Loop

objFile.Close
f.Close
```